# Should I use OR statements or LIKE statements in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I am doing an `INNER JOIN` on couple sub-queries. In this query I use a similar `WHERE` clause which has a `LIKE` statement; `WHERE bookName LIKE '%INTERVIEWS%'`.

But there are about five different variations of a `bookName` which has the word "INTERVIEWS". So would the query perform better if I did an `OR` statement for each variation, or should I do one `LIKE` statement for all the variations?

------------------ EDIT ------------------

Here is an example of what the query looks like with only a `LIKE` statement:

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM 
   books
WHERE
   bookName LIKE '%INTERVIEWS%';
```

Here is an example of what the query looks like with `OR` statements:

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM 
   books
WHERE
   bookName = 'INTERVIEWS WITH CELEBRITIES'
   OR
   bookName = 'ONGOING INTERVIEWS WITH STUDENTS'
   OR
   bookName = 'POLITICIAN INTERVIEWS'
   OR
   bookName = 'INTERVIEWS WHICH FAILED'
   OR
   bookName = 'INTERVIEWS WITH PROGRAMMERS';
```

Comment: More specific example, please - what are the variations? It is easy to _over-do it_ with a `LIKE` and match more than you intend.

Comment: Obviously, if you can shoehorn it into a single `LIKE`, it's going to perform better, because your other way executes 5 `LIKE` operations.  Unless you're executing a LIKE statement without a starting `%` against an indexed column, you're most likely going to incur a table scan for each LIKE, unless the database is smart enough to sort that out.  Check your query execution plans for each variation.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I posted an example of the queries could look like.

Comment: I don't think you could build a single `LIKE` to capture all of those `OR`s. Maybe you could with a lot of work but it is doubtful that it would perform any better. Is there an index on bookName? If not, create one. Then say `bookName IN ('a', 'b', 'c'...)`. That won't perform any different from `OR` but it is much easier to look at.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Wouldn't doing `WHERE bookName LIKE '%INTERVIEWS%'` work?

Comment: I would expect the ORs to perform better as the LIKE would certainly cause a table scan while the ORs could search an index (assuming the column is indexed). Why don't you run them and compare for yourself?

Comment: @chudapati09 Yes, but it would match these 5 *and* any other books with `INTERVIEWS` in the title. Is your intention to match all books that match that pattern, or just these 5?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I want the query to match all the books I listed in the query which used only `OR` statements.

Comment: @chudapati09 you're still not answering my question. Are `all the books in the query` also `all the books in the table that contain the word 'INTERVIEWS'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is multiple aspects to consider:

- You do not have an `index` on the bookName column: in this context that does not matter, the query is going to perform the same way by executing a clustered index scan or a table scan.
- You do have a `non clustered index` on the bookName column

  - this is a `non covering index` (scenario 1):
    in the second use case with the `OR` statement, you are likely to hit the `index tipping point`, where the query optimizer will decide **not** to use the `non clustered index`. In this context the `LIKE` will perform better by using an index scan. Read more on the [Kimberly Tripp's blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx).
  - this is a `covering index` (scenario 2):
    there is no tipping point for covering indexes. In this case, the second query will perform drastically better by using an `index seek` where the `LIKE` query will still have to do an `Index Scan`.

So if performance is critical, use a covering index

Here are the details, using [Adventure Works](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587)

Scenario 1

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Production.Product AS p
WHERE   Name LIKE '%mountain seat%'

SELECT  *
FROM    Production.Product AS p
WHERE   Name = 'LL Mountain Seat Assembly'
        OR Name = 'ML Mountain Seat Assembly'
        OR Name = 'HL Mountain Seat Assembly'
        OR Name = 'LL Mountain Seat/Saddle'
        OR Name = 'ML Mountain Seat/Saddle'
        OR Name = 'HL Mountain Seat/Saddle'
```

[image]

Scenario 2

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    Production.Product AS p
WHERE   Name LIKE '%mountain seat%'

SELECT  Name
FROM    Production.Product
WHERE   Name = 'LL Mountain Seat Assembly'
        OR Name = 'ML Mountain Seat Assembly'
        OR Name = 'HL Mountain Seat Assembly'
        OR Name = 'LL Mountain Seat/Saddle'
        OR Name = 'ML Mountain Seat/Saddle'
        OR Name = 'HL Mountain Seat/Saddle'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yea I spent some time modifying the query, and I got about the same execution time for both types of queries, one with only a `LIKE` statement and another one with `OR` statements. Like you predicted, since the column is not indexed, the `LIKE` statement preformed a second better.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking from a performance perspective - other choices such as contains and freetext may perform better. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx.

Assuming the scenario that you're developing is a user search page, freetext may be the better out of the box choice with SQL Server, since it supports word stemming (i.e. a search on interview would include interviews, interviewed, interviewer, etc.). It also support thesaurus matching, amongst other things.

There are other non-SQL Server choices that can be used but the barrier to entry is higher, such as Lucene/SOLR.

Edit: 
Getting started with contains and freetext (or containstable and freetexttable) requires you to enable full text indexing within your database. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142497.aspx for some getting started information.

Comment: I think this would have been really helpful if we had Full-Text Search configured, but I highly doubt we do.

Comment: @chudapati09 it's not like ordering a new server, it's a pretty easy feature to add (and it is quite common that it is already there, just not in use). That said, I don't know that you really need full-text search for the specific query you're asking about, where you're not really in need of `LIKE` at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the bookName column is indexed and the table has a substantial number of columns, the second option will definitely run more quickly because it will be ab index scan instead of a table scan.  If there is no index then they will be approximately the same because they will both require a table scan.

As for the idea of adding full text indexing, that is best for long columns of text, not short names like this.  I would stick with indexing the column if you need performance and doing a series of exact matches.